# Display path and filename in a minibuffer

Tags: minibuffer, interactive, find-file, default

Eval this code:

```
(defun xx-display-filename (filename)
  ""
  (interactive "Ffilename: ")
  (message (concat "Filename is: " filename)))
```

*Let's assume that I am editing a `~/.emacs.d/personal/custom.el` file in the current buffer.*

The function above, when invoked with `M-x xx-display-filename` displays a following text in a minibuffer:

```
filename: ~/.emacs.d/personal/
```

1. This is confusing. I can see a valid path but name of the file is missing. I would expect to see this:

   ```
   filename: ~/.emacs.d/personal/custom.el
   ```
2. This is confusing even more. When executed, this function writes a following line in `*Messages*` buffer:

   ```
   Filename is: ~/.emacs.d/personal/custom.el
   ```

   I would expect to see the same text as in a minibuffer:

   ```
   Filename is: ~/.emacs.d/personal/
   ```

So, the question is, How can I display whole path and filename of the currently edited file in a minibuffer and pass it as an argument to an interactive function?

Comment: Thank you for providing enough info to reproduce the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the documentation [for "Reading File Names" with elisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Reading-File-Names.html).

There you can read that normally `read-file-name` and therefore `interactive` with the code letter `F` provides the `default-directory` as initial input. You get the default file name if you press the down-arrow button.

Nevertheless, you can also insert some initial file name for `read-file-name` with its optional argument `initial`.

Your code could be modfified as follows to provide an initial file name as you want it.

```el
(defun xx-display-filename (filename)
  ""
  (interactive (list (read-file-name "filename: " nil nil nil (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name)))))
  (message (concat "Filename is: " filename)))
```

But, also note that using the initial input is depreciated. You should use the default value instead.

Answer (score 1):

@Tobias answers most of what your question asks. This bit was missing, however: why do you see a directory name inserted after the prompt for a file name, in the minibuffer?

That is controlled by user option **`insert-default-directory`**.  `C-h v` tells you:

> **`insert-default-directory`** is a variable defined in `minibuffer.el`.
>
> Its value is `t`
>
> Documentation:
>
> Non-`nil` means when reading a filename start with default dir in minibuffer.
>
> When the initial minibuffer contents show a name of a file or a directory,
>   typing `RETURN` without editing the initial contents is equivalent to typing
>   the default file name.
>
> If this variable is non-`nil`, the minibuffer contents are always
>   initially non-empty, and typing `RETURN` without editing will fetch the
>   default name, if one is provided.  Note however that this default name
>   is not necessarily the same as initial contents inserted in the minibuffer,
>   if the initial contents is just the default directory.
>
> If this variable is `nil`, the minibuffer often starts out empty.  In
>   that case you may have to explicitly fetch the next history element to
>   request the default name; typing `RETURN` without editing will leave
>   the minibuffer empty.
>
> For some commands, exiting with an empty minibuffer has a special meaning,
>   such as making the current buffer visit no file in the case of
>   `set-visited-file-name`.
>
> You can customize this variable.

Answer (score 0):

The lisp command `buffer-file-name` give the absolute path of the file a buffer is visiting which is the info you are looking for.

There is another mode for `interactive`, where you pass a list of arguments (see bullet 3 on https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html).  We can call `buffer-file-name` in that list:

```
(defun yy-display-filename (filename)
  ""
  (interactive (list (buffer-file-name)))
  (message (concat "Filename is: " filename)))
```

This appears to solve the problem you had.

I do know why the various letter codes to interactive all prompt with the current working directory.

Comment: `buffer-file-name` is not a command; it is not an interactive function.